# Sort a collection in Ember.Controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm inheriting some Ember.js code and for some reason the developer did not use Ember.ArrayController here, so I manually mixed in Ember.SortableMixin. Here's the code I'm trying to work with:

```
App.NflProjectionsController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.SortableMixin, {
  position: 'qb',
  site: 'FanDuel',

  type: 'nfl_weekly_projection',    
  isLoading: true,

  collection: [],

  isQB:     Ember.computed.equal('position', 'qb'),
  isWR:     Ember.computed.equal('position', 'wr'),
  isRB:     Ember.computed.equal('position', 'rb'),
  isTE:     Ember.computed.equal('position', 'te'),
  isK:      Ember.computed.equal('position', 'k'),
  isDEF:    Ember.computed.equal('position', 'def'),
  isFlex:   Ember.computed.equal('position', 'flex'),

  isFanDuel:     Ember.computed.equal('site', 'FanDuel'),
  isDraftKings:  Ember.computed.equal('site', 'DraftKings'),
  isDraftStreet: Ember.computed.equal('site', 'DraftStreet'),
  isFantasyAces: Ember.computed.equal('site', 'FantasyAces'),
  isDraftDay:    Ember.computed.equal('site', 'DraftDay'),

  actions: {
    choosePosition: function(type){
      this.set('collection', []);
      this.set('position', type);
    }, 

    chooseSite: function(type){
      this.set('collection', []);
      this.set('site', type);
    },

    sortBy: function(property) {
      this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
      this.set('sortAscending', !this.get('sortAscending'));
    }
  },

  positionObserver: function(){
    this.set('isLoading', true);
    var self = this;
    this.store.find(this.get('type'), {position: self.get('position'), site_id: self.get('site')}).then(function(collection){
      // console.log("here we are");
      if (self.get('collection').length == 0)
        self.set('collection', collection.toArray());
      self.set('isLoading', false);
    });
  }.observes('position').on('init'),

  siteObserver: function(){
    this.set('isLoading', true);
    var self = this;
    this.store.find(this.get('type'), {position: self.get('position'), site_id: self.get('site')}).then(function(collection){
      if (self.get('collection').length == 0)
        self.set('collection', collection.toArray());
      self.set('isLoading', false);
    });
  }.observes('site').on('init')

});
```

I created the `sortBy` function and am trying to figure out how I can sort the array that gets set to the controller's `collection` property. All the examples I've seen work directly with `Ember.ArrayController`. Is it possible to sort using this existing code and `Ember.Controller`?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you *don't* want to just use an `ArrayController`?  If your `collection` property can be thought of as the backing model for this page, then it would be standard practice to replace the `collection` property by populating the `model` property via the underlying route.

If you want to keep the existing page that you have, then you're on the right track with `Ember.SortableMixin`.  Originally, I thought you need to use the `Ember.ArrayProxy` to take advantage of `sortBy`, but @Kingpin2k kindly pointed out in the comments that Ember actually extends the array prototype directly, so even this isn't necessary.

@Kingpin2k put together a nice jsbin that shows this in action:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gepeko/1/edit

Comment: `sortBy` is added via the array prototype extensions included by ember, you don't need to wrap things with Ember.A or ArrayProxy to use them.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gepeko/1/edit

Comment: @Kingpin2k Thank you for the clarification!  I didn't realize Ember extends the js array prototype.  I will revise my answer now.